# jQuery select all elements inside particular parent elements

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

I need to loop through all table elements, somewhere keeping an index and then loop through all elements inside those tables. Idea is to add information into database about elements inside tables together with their table index.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
$('table').each(function(index) {
    $(this).find('*').each(function() {
        /* do magic */
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Simply use children() to select all elements of parent:

```
$('table').children().hide();
```

Comment: `.children()` only goes 1 level deep. `find()` is recursive.